# Making math behaving like \mathit

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I often use descriptive names for predicates, terms and functions. However, due to the lack of kerning they don't look nice.

For example

```
$offer = surface \times force(now)$
```

renders as

[image]

Thus to avoid it use `\mathit`.

```
$\mathit{offer = surface \times force(now)}$
```

which renders as

[image]

which, arguably, looks better and it is easier to read.

To avoid to type `\mathit`m, I defined

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{italics}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{m}{it}
```

and

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{a}{\mathalpha}{italics}{`a}
...
\DeclareMathSymbol{z}{\mathalpha}{italics}{`z}
\DeclareMathSymbol{A}{\mathalpha}{italics}{`A}
...
\DeclareMathSymbol{z}{\mathalpha}{italics}{`Z}
```

**Question(s)**

Is this the "proper" way to do this?

What are the disadvantages/drawbacks of this approach? (I can use `\mathnormal` to go back  to the standard behaviour, and I know  that, for example, for the product of `f` and `i` I have to use `f{}i` to prevent the ligature).

Comment: The typographically correct way to use words in equations is to print them in roman, i.e., `\mathrm{offer} = \mathrm{surface}\times\mathrm{force}(\mathrm{now})`.

Comment: @ChrisS Math variables, terms, functions and predicates are typically written in italics. Do you write `$y=z \times f(z)$` or `$\mathrm{y} = \mathrm{z} \times \mathrm{f}(\mathrm{z})$`.

Comment: The proper way surely isn't changing codes for the letters. Use semantic markup: `offer` is the product of five quantities, `\var{offer}` can be the name of a variable.

Comment: there's no need to declare a new font family for this, one is already allocated for \mathit so you can use that one.

Comment: If you do this you would need `\mathnormal` around every 1-letter variable not just using `{}` to break ligatures, it's a different font not just different kerning and ligature information.

Comment: @egreg Where do you stop with semantic markup? If `offer` is the product of 5 quantities (variables), then, for consistency, it should be `\var{o}\var{f}\var{f}\var{e}\var{r}`.

Comment: @Guido I don't understand: `\var` is for *multiletter identifiers*. The product of a, b and c will still be denoted by `abc`. Of course it's the author's duty to make things not confusing.

Comment: @egreg For the argument of semantic markup, you have to go all the way.  A variable is a variable no matter of how many letters its identifiers has. So one should use `\var{ab}` for the variable "ab" and `\var{c}` for the variable `c`. Also. for the copyeditor/supervisor argument in your (otherwise technically excellent, as usual) answer.

Comment: @Guido No I would disagree, as I commented in my answer, letters  (in the absence of other markup) assumed to be denoting separate variables in TeX. That is why they are spaced out as your original image shows. It can in some contexts be useful to mark them up explicitly, especially if converting to other formats, but they shouldn't use the `\mathit` font in any case, so if you wanted `\var{c}` markup you would need a more complicated definition that checked on the length of the string and chose an  appropriate font.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends on several factors. If your math formulas are *all* built like that, then you might be justified in changing the mathcodes for the letters, although I recommend you not to do it.

Prefer a semantic markup: multiletter identifiers denote either variables or functions; define two commands, say `\var` and `\func` and type your formula as

```
\[
\var{offer}=\var{surface}\cdot\func{force}(\var{now})
\]
```

(don't use `\times`, please!). Now you have the freedom of choosing whatever representation for variables and functions you need, for instance

```
\newcommand{\var}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\newcommand{\func}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
```

When your supervisor or a journal copy editor will tell you “Nice, but functions should be typeset in upright letters”, you'll answer “Wait a minute“, change the second line into

```
\newcommand{\func}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
```

and recompile. Would it be the same with the change to the math codes?

Is it harder to type? I don't think so, particularly if you are an Emacs expert who's able to define a couple of shorthands.

---

Changing the math code of all letters is quite easy, as the code is repetitive. Don't forget to redeclare `\mathit` with `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet` in order not to waste a math family.

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{italics}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathit}{italics}

\makeatletter
\count@=`a \advance\count@\m@ne
\@whilenum{\count@<`z}\do{%
  \advance\count@\@ne
  \begingroup\lccode`A=\count@
  \lowercase{\endgroup
    \DeclareMathSymbol{A}{\mathalpha}{italics}{`A}%
  }%
}
\count@=`A \advance\count@\m@ne
\@whilenum{\count@<`Z}\do{%
  \advance\count@\@ne
  \begingroup\lccode`A=\count@
  \lowercase{\endgroup
    \DeclareMathSymbol{A}{\mathalpha}{italics}{`A}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

The loops can be simplified with `expl3`:

```
\usepackage{expl3}

\DeclareSymbolFont{italics}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathit}{italics}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nnnn { `A } { 1 } { `Z }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \char_set_lccode:nn { `A } { #1 }
  \char_set_lccode:nn { `B } { #1 + 32 }
  \tl_to_lowercase:n
   {
    \group_end:
    \DeclareMathSymbol{A}{\mathalpha}{italics}{`A}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{B}{\mathalpha}{italics}{`B}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The main problem, which requires using the `\lowercase` trick, is that it's the only way to generate a character token knowing its character code.

With a recent version of `expl3` (released after 2015-09-09), one can avoid the `\lowercase` trick using `\char_generate:nn`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\DeclareSymbolFont{italics}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathit}{italics}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nnnn { `A } { 1 } { `Z }
 {
  \exp_args:Nf \DeclareMathSymbol{\char_generate:nn{#1}{11}}{\mathalpha}{italics}{#1}
 }
\int_step_inline:nnnn { `a } { 1 } { `z }
 {
  \exp_args:Nf \DeclareMathSymbol{\char_generate:nn{#1}{11}}{\mathalpha}{italics}{#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
offer=surface\cdot force(now)
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason why the global reassigning the letters in math mode is not good idea was mentioned in another answer and comments. But if you really need this, then you can do:

```
\everymath{\it}\everydisplay{\it}
```

at beginning of the document. If you need to keep the numbers in roman style, then you can set:

```
\def\mathcodes#1{\mathcode`#1=\numexpr\mathcode`#1-"7000\relax 
   \ifx#10\else\expandafter\mathcodes\fi}
\mathcodes1234567890
```

This means, for example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\everymath{\it}\everydisplay{\it}
\def\mathcodes#1{\mathcode`#1=\numexpr\mathcode`#1-"7000\relax 
   \ifx#10\else\expandafter\mathcodes\fi}
\mathcodes1234567890
\begin{document}

$offer = surface \times force(now) + 1$

\end{document}
```

If you are using plain TeX then you can use `\itvariables` command which is provided after `\input ams-math` or `\input opmac`. This command sets mathcodes of all letters to the text italic math family (as default). For example:

```
\input ams-math \itvariables

$offer = surface \times force(now) + 2$

\bye
```

Comment: ``Class scrartcl Warning: Usage of deprecated font command `\it'! You should note, that in 1994 font command `\it' has been defined for compatiblitiy to Script 2.0 only. Now, after two decades of LaTeX2e and NFSS2, you shouldn't use such commands any longer and within KOMA-Script usage of `\it' is definitely deprecated.`` Try with `memoir` for another surprise.

Comment: My solution is working independent of the used format (LaTeX or plainTeX). I always prefer such independent solutions. I know that `\it` works in LaTeX too. If it is or isn't deprecated in LaTeX is not so important to me as the mentioned independence.

Comment: `\it` won't be supported by KOMA-script with one of the next versions. Why should it? It is deeprecated for 20 years and is only around for compatibility. But that is already said in the warning issued by KOMA. The point is, that the old (deprecated) font commands are provided by the class, *not* the format.

Comment: I hope that if LaTeX users have such problems with `\it` then they are able to simply substitute this command to something more acceptable. This is only LaTeX problem.

Comment: `\it` isn't defined in the latex format, some classes notably the standard ones such as `article` may load a package to define it for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @wipet Well, since the question is about LaTeX, it is *your* problem to provide a working answer for this setting, or else telling that it is for Plain and may not work with LaTeX, which is the point of my first comment.

Comment: The edit is wrong: with it `\mathbf{1}` will have no effect.

Comment: I provide working example which works in plain TeX and LaTeX. I've tried this example in LaTeX too and it works.

Comment: The edit isn't wrong: There is an implication: if you need to keep the numbers in roman style ... The `\mathbf{1}` keeps numbers in roman style, i. e. it does nothing.

Comment: Well, you should add the main implications of your code.

Comment: Some (LaTeX...) packages use `\everymath` and `\everydisplay` for their highly respectable own purposes; thus it would be better not to overwrite them but just add to their contents.

Answer (score 4):

I would agree with egreg that it is far better to make the markup match the meaning here and mark up each identifier separately. The math markup in TeX, as well as the default fonts, are designed on the idea that adjacent letters are separate variables, typically with implied multiplication or concatenation operators.

However if you are not convinced and want to default to the text italic font there is no need to allocate a new math font for this, it is already set up for use with `\mathit` you just need to make it escape the implied grouping that `\mathit`  implies.

```
\documentclass{article}


\let\v\mathit
\begin{document}


$\mathit{offer = surface \times force(now)}$



$\v{offer} = \v{surface} \times \v{force}(\v{now})$%%%USE THIS

\everymath{\mathit{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam\relax}}\tmp}


$offer = surface \times force(now)$

\end{document}
```

Comment: The last one (`\everymath`) changes numerals to italics as well.

Comment: @Guido It does exactly the same as your suggested use of `\mathit` around the whole expression, yes.

Comment: I was a bit sloppy:-) The idea was to wrap each "string" with  `\mathit` (and indeed I use a shortcut for it).

Comment: @Guido you could do as you suggest resetting the matchcode of letters, but as noted here you can re-use the font slot assigned to \mathit (there are only 16 so allocating the same font to two slots is expensive) but I wouldn't do it, I have done the above with `\mathsf` where you want everything including digits to be in sans in presentations or very elementary worksheets

Comment: Some packages use `\everymath` and `\everydisplay` for their highly respectable own purposes; thus it would be better not to overwrite them but just add to their contents.

Comment: @jfbu perhaps although I'd only do this at all in highly controlled circumstances... but if you want that:  `\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\mathit{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam\relax}}\tmp}`

Comment: ah, and thus people reading this will know what to do with `\everydisplay` too. There is some strange alchemist signature with an unknown to me Unicode sign at the end of your comment ;-) (strangely copy paste to emacs `*scratch*`  simply displays `}`)